# set JVM heap size to be atleast 8GB

Tags: java, jvm

I want to set the JVM heap size to be atleast 8GB. Can I do that with below configuration? I see that the max heap size is 4GB from the command below and I am not sure how to set it to 8GB?

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'HeapSize|PermSize|ThreadStackSize'
     intx CompilerThreadStackSize                   = 0                                   {pd product}
    uintx ErgoHeapSizeLimit                         = 0                                   {product}
    uintx HeapSizePerGCThread                       = 87241520                            {product}
    uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 264241152                           {product}
    uintx LargePageHeapSizeThreshold                = 134217728                           {product}
    uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 4206886912                          {product}
     intx ThreadStackSize                           = 1024                                {pd product}
     intx VMThreadStackSize                         = 1024                                {pd product}
```

Comment: That’s an odd question. If a particular default setting is 4GB, why should that imply that you can’t set it to 8GB? Because it has “Max” in its name? Would you ask the same question about any other setting?

Answer (score 4):

To set the minimum heap size use `-Xms` e.g. `-Xms8g`

To set the maximum heap size use `-Xmx` e.g. `-Xmx16g`

Of course this only controls the heap and doesn't control any of the other memory regions such as stacks for thread, code storage, shared libraries, direct memory, GUI component etc.

Comment: Thanks now that I know how to set heap size I still wonder how it is possible given  uintx MaxHeapSize  := 4206886912 (4GB)

Comment: You can't do it. To set 8 GB heap, you need minimum 8 GB RAM unix node.

Comment: @ravindra technically you need at least 9 - 10 GB of free *virtual memory* to create an 8 GB heap, however while the JVM will start with more heap than you have memory very quickly your application will grind to a halt, as will your machine. This is because the GC assumes it is running in random access memory, not partially on disk. It is a very bad idea, but you are not prevented from doing it (which is perhaps worse)

Comment: When my son turned 8, three years ago, I bought him a small machine to play games on which has 8 GB in it.  I suggest you get at least 16 GB if not 128 GB you are going to do any thing more serious.

Comment: Yes. I agree with you. I generally configure 50% available RAM as heap for my application